# Angular speed of rotation of received IQ samples

Tags: regression, signal-processing

I would like to find the speed of rotation of received IQ samples caused by a carrier frequency offset. The plot below shows 50 samples at a time. I have tried linear regression on the points but the model becomes undefined for angles close to 90 (should have realized this before trying). After that I tried converting the data to polar coordinates but am not sure how to perform regression on polar data. I would appreciate being pointed in the right direction to solve this problem!

[image: IQ samples over time]

Comment: Do you have values as function of time? Linear representation? Did you try running an FFT/DFT?

Comment: The main frequency will indicate the rate of rotation - the cycle is related to the frequency

Comment: Yes I have the complex values as a function of time. I understand there are other ways to correct a carrier frequency offset using the DFT, however, I thought it would be interesting to directly measure the rate of rotation of these points.

Comment: This is the efficient way - what is the advantage you are trying to gain?

Comment: Why not post at DSP SE? What percentage of Math SE even knows what "IQ" stands for?

Comment: There is no advantage I just thought this was an interesting mathematical problem and I would like to figure out how to solve it this way. Perhaps I could post on DSP SE but they would also just suggest using the DFT. I thought this was more of a mathematical problem since it does not require knowledge of what IQ samples are.

Comment: Sure, it does not require knowledge of what IQ samples are, but this is not a self-contained mathematical problem, which is why you have been mostly ignored so far. You present no block diagram, no mathematics. Most people looking at it have no idea what to do with it. It should be possible to answer a question without consulting Haykin.

Comment: After a bit of searching I have found that this problem falls under circular statistics and the data can be considered diametrically bimodal. The problem is to find the mean angle of each overlapping window of the data. Over time we should see the mean angle change and from that we can find the angular speed (given sample rate). If I have time to complete this I will type it up and update this problem with the math

Comment: @CalebMartin Ideally, such information should be in the question itself, rather than in the comment section.